# Insert NA elements in vector

Tags: r

I have a vector:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4)
```

I would  like to add 23 `NA` elements before each element of `x`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe like this?

```
c(sapply(x, function(x) c(rep(NA,23),x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with vectorization

```
replace(rep(NA, 23*length(x) + length(x)), rep(c(FALSE, TRUE), c(23, 1)), x) 
#[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
#[43] NA NA NA NA NA  2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  3 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
#[85] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  4
```

---

Or another option is to create a `matrix`, replace the last row with 'x' and convert it to `vector`

```
m1 <- matrix(rep(rep(NA, 24), length(x)), nrow = length(x))
m1[,24] <- x
c(t(m1))
```